# IDropSourceNotify - how to implement

Tags: delphi, winapi, drag-and-drop

I want to implement a OLE Drag&Drop feature. Doing this, I have to detect the mouse button is clicked and moved. Than I call `DoDragDrop` to start the Drag&Drop feature.

To receive the Drag&Drop feature, I have to call `RegisterDragDrop` before of it to register a window as a target of the Drag&Drop operation. Like the most applications, my main window based on several sub windows: `TreeView`, `ListView`, `Edit`, etc.. With `IDropTarget::DragOver` I can detect, if the target sub window accepts the Drag&Drop operation. This works fine, if I drag an object from a different application and the mouse cursor shows as well, if the target sub window accept the Drag&Drop operation.

But if I start the Drag&Drop feature inside my application with `DoDragDrop` the mouse cursor does now change automatically. Why?

So I can use the `IDropSource::GiveFeedback` method to change the cursor of the target sub window. But I can't find out, which sub window has to change the cursor.

If I'm right, the `IDropSourceNotify` should provide this informations. But how can I involve this class into the Drag&Drop operation?

Additional, I don't understand, why I have to handle the mouse cursor by my self, if the source window is inside my application - but it will be handled automatically, if the source window is inside an other application.

Last but not least, if I change the cursor of my sub window inside `IDropSource::GiveFeedback` it will be shown like I changed it. But since the my main thread is inside `DoDragDrop` I wonder how Windows detect the changed cursor. If I'm right, Windows ask my application with the `WM_NCHITTEST` message, which cursor should be shown. But how does my application answer this message, while the main thread is blocked inside `DoDragDrop`?

I'm working with Delphi XE4 on a Window 7 system.

Comment: your object must implement 2 interface `IDropSourceNotify` and `IDropSource`. you pass `IDropSource` to `DoDragDrop`, `IDropSourceNotify` system got when call `QueryInterface` on `IDropSource`

Comment: @RbMm I can't see how IDropSourceNotify is relevant here. IDropSourceNotify was introduced with Vista and IDropSource (including the ability to control the cursor) was introduced in W2K.

Comment: @SpeedFreak - question was "how implement `IDropSourceNotify`" , and so what that  `IDropSourceNotify` was introduced later ?

Comment: @RbMm You're right; I shouldn't have addressed my reply to you but to the OP. My brain must have had the XY filter enabled because it completely ignored the (irrelevant) IDropSourceNotify part of the original question.

Comment: @RbMm, SpeedFreak: Thank you for your answers. You are right: My question was not clear - I asked different things. But now I understood how to handle `IDropSourceNotify` and I have the default cursors. I'm happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop source should not make any assumptions about the drop target - and should never attempt to modify the UI of the target.
In other words: Do not mess with the cursor property of the control under the cursor.

The return value from [`IDropSource.GiveFeedback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693723(v=vs.85).aspx) instructs Windows to either use the standard drag drop cursors or let you handle that detail yourself.

If you return `DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS` then the standard cursor corresponding to the current drop effect (the parameter passed to `GiveFeedback`) will be used. If you return `S_OK` then you can set the cursor by calling the [`SetCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx) API function.

I would recommend that you just return `DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS`.

Actually unless you have a burning desire to learn the inner details of COM based drag and drop I would recommend you Google "drag drop delphi" and use one of the already available libraries.